# Vulnerability TrustManager

Tags: android-security, trustmanager, x509trustmanager

Our app has been in the Play Market for 4 years.

Before the last build, we added AppMetrica in the app:

```
implementation 'com.yandex.android:mobmetricalib:3.13.1'
implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.yandex.android:mobmetricapushlib:1.5.1'
```

The project with these instruments was successfully uploaded into the Play Market without any notifications (errors or warnings). In a few weeks after that, I made minor changes in sending reports in the AppMetrica and received the following notification from Google:

"We reviewed XXX, with package name XXX, and found that your app uses software that contains security vulnerabilities for users. Apps with these vulnerabilities can expose user information or damage a user’s device, and may be considered to be in violation of our Malicious Behavior policy.
Below is the list of issues and the corresponding APK versions that were detected in your recent submission. Please migrate your apps to use the updated software as soon as possible and increment the version number of the upgraded APK.

Vulnerability TrustManager You can find more information about TrustManager in this Google Help Center article."

We don't use TrustManager and his classes in the project.

What can be the possible reason for rejecting? Is it possible that this rejection was made by mistake? How can we find out what is the reason for that? Can AppMetrica cause this setback and should we stop using it?

Also, in the rejection text they said you can set up the network config (https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config) in the app -- how can it help?

We are fighting this trouble for two weeks and we hope for your help